# ¿Como activar un formulario a un usuario, al instante en que el administrador lo autorice desde el sistema?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Necesito un ejemplo y saber si lo que necesito se puede hacer; verán estoy trabajando en un sistema escolar y necesito que cuando un usuario necesite entrar a  cierto modulo, solicite al administrador la autorización para entrar a ese modulo (esto ya lo he logrado).

Quisiera que el administrador le de autorizar desde el sistema y que inmediatamente le muestre el formulario al usuario que ha solicitado y que al terminar su proceso, nuevamente no se pueda ver el formulario.

Agradecería mucho de su ayuda, ya que no logro hacer algo así.

Comment: Es bastante amplia la pregunta, si se puede. Una manera es usar server sent events https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Server-sent_events/utilizando_server_sent_events_sse

Comment: gracias @Emeeus tratare de adaptar tu ejemplo a mi código, gracias por tu respuesta